# how use adb socket to install app or put file to mobile without using adb command?

Tags: android

How can I use adb to install an apk on the phone or push something to the phone's file system?

I can uninstall an app by package name like this:

```
CString cmd;
cmd.AppendFormat(_T("shell:pm uninstall %s"), PackageName );
adb_write(adb_s,(LPCTSTR)cmd); // adb_s the socket connect the server
```

Comment: Are you asking how to install an APK programmatically from the phone itself, or over adb command line?

Comment: no ,i write a  tool works on the windows pc ,some days ago i use a pipe to comminuate to adb.exe ,but now i write a scocket connect to adb server ,and send meg to the server ,then read return meg from it.i have read some info from the adb source code ,find  " fd = adb_connect("sync:")  " in file_sync_client.c ,so what i want is how  use this method to install app ?

Comment: some thing like this , link <br>http://code.google.com/p/android-fb2png/source/browse/adb_screenshoot.c ,the guy use socket get info from framebuffer,i wan use this method to install app